# Linq Query to Search "Many" in one to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Hey guys I have EF classes of Book and Comments.

A book can have many comments.

How can I search for a book with any comment that contains my search text?

My method looks like this as of now...

```
public IEnumerable<Book> Search(string commentText)
{

     IQueryable<Book> books = _context.Books;

     books.Where() //need to filter by commentText here

     return books;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
books.Where(a=>a.Comments.Any(b=>b.CommentText.Contains(commentText)));
```